# Implement video player with volume control,Stop in android

Tags: java, android

Is there any method or way to add volume and stop button in android MediaController class,Or could anyone suggest me any video player library with volume and stop control

Comment: https://github.com/denivip/avideo

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Androids native [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) you can set a [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) on the video view using [setMediaController()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setMediaController(android.widget.MediaController)). This automatically add play / pause / seek functionality. [Here's](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_VideoView_and_MediaController_Tutorial) a quick tutorial on how to set up a simple video view with media controller.

Also some code to get you started:

```
ViewView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.my_video_view);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

As for volume control, this is usually done using the device dedicated volume buttons. If you *really* need to add your own custom volume controls, you'll have to do a little more work by creating your own custom media controls. This is a large topic by itself, but [here's](http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/custom-android-media-controller) a good starting point.

Hope thats of some help.